# Есть данные в формате txt, записанные в 2 столбца.Как с помощью этих данных можно построить график в python? Ругается, что строковый тип переменных

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

[image: Код для загрузки файла и перевода во float][image: Данные в формате txt записанные в два столбика таким образом]

Есть данные в формате txt, записанные в 2 столбца. Как с помощью этих данных можно построить график в python? Ругается, что строковый тип переменных. Не могу преобразовать в числовой формат. Помогитееее!

Comment: Добавьте в ваш вопрос код чтения файла

Comment: Вы знаете о существовании функции `numpy.loadtxt`? попробуйте `numpy.loadtxt('43.txt')`

Comment: Добавила код, с помощью которого пыталась открыть документ и конвертировать тип данных, 43 или 49 в названии файла не ошибка, просто они одинаковые

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [numpy.loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), как посоветовал в комментарии [@Pak Uula](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1280460/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5-txt-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD#comment2256236_1280460):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = np.loadtxt(filename)    # читаем файл в 2D матрицу
plt.plot(m[:, 0], m[:, 1])  # строим график - ось `X` - первый столбец, `Y` - второй 
plt.show()
```

Comment: @МарияИльичёва вы прочитали замечания к вашему вопросу в комментариях? Такие вопросы обычно закрываются сообществом в виду нарушений привил.